# Prometheus config to ignore scraping of metrics for a specific namespace in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, configuration, monitoring, prometheus, istio

Is there a way to configure prometheus to ignore scraping metrics for all the resources belonging to a particular namespace? I am not able to figure it out by reading the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can drop targets with `relabel_config` by using `drop` action. From the [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config):

> `drop`: Drop targets for which `regex` matches the concatenated `source_labels`.

Example:

```yaml
  relabel_configs:
  # This will ignore scraping targets from 'ignored_namespace_1', 
  # 'ignored_namespace_2', and 'ignored_namespace_N'.
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    action: drop
    regex: ignored_namespace_1|ignored_namespace_2|ignored_namespace_N
```

Comment: I tried using this config and it's now working. which role did you use?

Comment: @Von `__meta_kubernetes_namespace` appears for roles that represent namespaced objects: service, ingress, endpoints, and pod. Nodes are not namespaced and so there's no namespace label.

Comment: I Am trying to exclude namespace from being scraped by prometheus by using below config. But the metrcis still appears in prometheus.

scrape_configs:
    - job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
      relabel_configs:
   
          - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
            action: drop
            regex: <namespace_name>

Comment: @Von Consider asking a question with it. Bring all the details (e.g. examples of those metrics).

Comment: Is it possible to do the oposite? Like include only specific metrics by regex or list

Comment: @sem10 yep, use `keep` instead of `drop`, everything else is the same.